# Hibernate erase MariaDB table on redeployment

Tags: hibernate, mariadb

I don't understand why Hibernate keeps erasing a table content everytime I redeploy my JEE7 web-app, despite there is no exception in the server output and the persistence, datasource, facade and entities are working well.
I'm using MariaDB as database and HeidiSQL for database management.
For some tests purpose I'm filling a table with HeidiSQL to try some forms though the table gets erased when I redeploy the app.

Here is the persistence.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1"    
        xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
            http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="em" transaction-type="JTA">
        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/mariadbds</jta-data-source>
        <class>my.company.myapp.model.Entity1</class>
        <class>my.a.myapp.model.Entity2</class>
        <class>my.company.myapp.model.Entity3</class>
        <class>my.company.myapp.model.Entity4</class>
        <class>my.company.myapp.model.Entity5</class>
        <class>my.company.myapp.model.Entity6</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>
                <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
               <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Thanks for any idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change that property

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>
```

by

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
```